# How to set default enum value while using Hibernate's @Enumerated?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have a column in my DB table that I want to map to Java object.
I marked the chosen column with annotation:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RoleType code;
```

The problem is that on the DB side, except of values that I am interested of, there are invalid (in context of a task I am doing) values, so I want to map them to "Unknown" type.

```
ADMIN ("ADMIN "),
CLIENT ("CLIENT"),
SOMEBODY ("SOMEBODY"),
UNKNOWN ("UNKNOWN");
```

Trying doing the above I got Hibernate mapping error.
Is it possible to map values different than 3 mentioned in enum (ADMIN, CLIENT, SOMEBODY) to some default enum value (i.e. UNKNOWN) using Hibernate?

EDIT:

To make things clearer

How values on DB side should be mapped on Java side:

```
TYPE_1  --->  UNKNOWN
ADMIN  --->  ADMIN
CLIENT  --->  CLIENT
SOMEBODY  --->  SOMEBODY
TYPE_2  --->  UNKNOWN
SOMEBODY_2  --->  UNKNOWN
```

Comment: your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could run an update query to make them all unknown, but if you dont want to do that, you can make your own usertype:
http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/01/better-enum-mapping-with-hibernate.html